# Angular Key-Value how to insert new Key-Value using html

Tags: html, angular, key-value

this is the class i use

```
 export class Product
    {
      id: string;
      title: string;
      description:string;
      numbersOfBuyers2Price: {[key: number]: number};
      category: string;
      img: string;
      endDate: number;
    }
```

the function that save the new product

```
onSaveProduct()
  {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.mode === 'create')
    {
      this.productService.addProduct(
        this.form.value.title,
        this.form.value.description,
        this.form.value.priceArray,
        this.form.value.category,
        this.form.value.img,
        this.form.value.endDate
      );
    }
}
```

the html for create to new product

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSaveProduct()">
  <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0"><tr>
    <td>
      <mat-label>Title:</mat-label>
      <input formControlName="title" matInput>
   </td>
    <td>
      <mat-label>Category:</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName ="category">
    </td>
    <td>
      <mat-label>IMG:</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName ="img">
    </td>
    <td>
      <mat-label>End Date:</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName ="endDate">
    </td>
  </tr></table>
  <button mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit">Save product</button>
</form>
```

i'm trying to adding multiple keyValues to numbersOfBuyers2Price using the html component,
i found only how to display them with *ngFor

Comment: Your question is not clear. You can set keys with the basic JavaScript syntax `product.numbersOfBuyers2Price[15] = 20`

Comment: in the TypeScript file i can add it with product.numbersOfBuyers2Price[15] = 20, but im trying to add it with the html file, that the user input is from the html pass to numbersOfBuyers2Price

Comment: There's a strict architecture in Angular, you're not supposed to create logic for modifying the state of objects in the HTML. Instead design your UI in HTML like you've done so far and call a function from the HTML template. I'll make a quick example

Answer (score 0):

You could  add UI to the HTML template to add new key value pairs to a member of your component clas. Then when the form is submitted you can use that in your `onSaveProduct` function.

#### HTML

```
    <td>
      <mat-label>New Buyers2Price:</mat-label>
      <input matInput [formControl]="newKey">
      <input matInput [formControl]="newValue">
      <button (click)="addKeyValue()">Add</button>
    </td>
```

#### TS

```
class YourComponent {
  private buyer2price: {[key: number]: nuber} = {};
  public newKey = new FormControl('');
  public newValue = new FormControl('');

  public function addKeyValue() {
    this.buyer2price[this.newKey.value] = this.newValue.value;
  }
```